# Security while casting my YouTube on a smart TV

Tags: google

I was wondering if casting from my YouTube account on my phone onto someone's tv gives access to my YouTube account to the owner of the tv once I stop casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The TV is not *authorised* to access your account and your account token is not given to the TV in order to display. The stream from your authenticated account is redirected to the TV.